# Limit involving integer part

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

Is my working for the following limit correct? I want to check whether $$\lim_{x\to 0}x \left[ \frac{a}{x}\right] = a$$
for $a>0$. I approached this by using the definition of the integer function. Namely
$$a=\lim_{x\to 0}x\left(\frac{a}{x}-1\right)\leq \lim_{x\to0^+} x \left[ \frac{a}{x}\right] = \lim_{x\to 0}x\left\lfloor \frac{a}{x}\right\rfloor\leq \lim_{x\to 0}x\left(\frac{a}{x}\right).$$
And similarly for the left hand limit but using the fact that
$$y \leq \lceil y \rceil\leq y+1$$

Comment: If $[a]$ is integer part, then what is $\lfloor a \rfloor$?

Comment: @zkutch It's the floor function. When approaching $0$ from the right $a/x> 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\geq 0$ we have $a=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x(a/x-1)\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x[a/x]\leq \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x(a/x+1)=a$, then use the squeeze theorem. For $x<0$ the inequalities flip.

Comment: Can the lower bound come from $x[a/x]\geq x(a/x-1)$?

Comment: Yes, the bounds come from $b-1\leq [b]\leq b+1$, which is true for any real number $b$.

Comment: (Pedantic point) It is not true that $x(a/x - 1) \le x [a/x] \le x(a/x + 1)$.  This is true for $x \ge 0$.  The inequalities go the other direction for $x < 0$, though the same "squeezing" still works.

Comment: Good point, I adjusted the argument.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything particularly wrong with the approach given (aside from the pedantic point that the sign of $x$ can change the direction of the inequalities), but it seems like a little bit of overkill.  There is no need to bring in the greatest integer function, the floor function (which is just another name for the greatest integer function), and ceiling function.

The key point is that, for any real $x$,
$$ x \le [x] < x+1. $$
From this, it immediately follows that
$$\frac{a}{x} \le \left[ \frac{a}{x} \right] < \frac{a}{x} + 1.$$
The desired result then follows from the squeeze theorem (though if you want to be *really* careful, you might want to pay special attention to the sign of $x$, i.e. take the limit from both sides of zero).  For example,
$$ a = \lim_{x\searrow 0} x \left(\frac{x}{a} \right)
\le \lim_{x\searrow 0} x \left[ \frac{x}{a} \right]
< \lim_{x \searrow 0} x \left( \frac{x}{a} + 1\right)
= a. $$
The left-hand limit is identical, but with the direction of the inequalities reversed.